# Can Postgres 13 stored procedures return multiple result sets similar to SQL Server?

Tags: postgresql, multiple-resultsets

I tried to search for it in the official docs but no luck.
Can Postgres 13 stored procedures return multiple result sets similar to SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to return a result set by executing a plain query - no, such syntax is not supported in PL/pgSQL.

If you mean to return a result set by using a cursor - yes, PostgreSQL stored procedures can return cursors too.

You can define multiple cursor output parameters: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: Is there an announced plan to support such syntax?

Comment: I don't know such plans. As I understand, there is no need to implement this feature. Cursors are the PostgreSQL way to return datasets. If you are interested to know which features are going to be implemented, you can study the site [Commitfests](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/).

Comment: Thx. Do you by any chance know why PG folks do not maintain their open source code in GitHub?

Comment: PostgreSQL is a few decades older than GitHub, that might be the reason

Comment: As I understand, they established their way to develop the code, and it still works well.